# Using iText in VB6

Tags: vb6, itext

We have a legacy app that is written in VB6 which we would like to use iText with. Is there an iText DLL that can be included in a VB6 application for creating PDF's?

Thanks in advance

Alan Liddle

Comment: [iText is AGPLed](http://itextpdf.com/pricing), are you sure you want to open source your app?

Answer (score 1):

**iTextSharp doesn't have a COM interface**.
The way you can use the DLL with VB6 is using a middleware project.

First create a .NET project with COM interoperablity. For example:
http://www.geeksengine.com/article/create-dll.html

Next, use this project for link and use the iTextSharp DLL.

The idea is that every PDF feature you need to do in your VB6 project will use that VB.NET project (COM interoperable) you created before.

Recap:

VB6 Project ===> VB.NET Project ===> iTextSharp

Hope it helps!